# gdal_vrtmerge.py vs. gdalbuildvrt

Tags: gdal, vrt, gdal-merge, gdalbuildvrt

In the [`gdalbuildvrt` documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html), I read

> This utility is somehow equivalent to the gdal_vrtmerge.py utility [...]

So what is the difference (if any) between `gdalbuildvrt` and `gdal_vrtmerge.py`?

**What does "somehow equivalent" mean** here?

1. Is one an alias for the other?
2. Do they have the same command line interface?
   (I.e., do they accept the same parameters and options,
   *and* do so with the same semantics?)

   (It seems so.)
3. Did one replace or deprecate the other?
4. Should one be preferred over the other?

And where can I find more information about `gdal_vrtmerge.py`? It doesn't seem to be included in my GDAL installation, but it's in the GDAL sources at `gdal/swig/python/samples/gdal_vrtmerge.py` ([download](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples/gdal_vrtmerge.py) | [view on trac](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples/gdal_vrtmerge.py)) on `trunk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python script is older but the executable is not an exact rewrite in C++. As you can see from the history the latest real change to the gdal_vrtmerge was done about 7 years ago [in revision 20672](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples/gdal_vrtmerge.py?rev=20672).

1) Not exactly, but probably `gdalbuildvrt` was close to `gdal_vrtmerge.py` in GDAL 1.6 many years ago.

2) Probably, but not guaranteed because they are not developed hand in hand.

3) `gdalbuildvrt` is obviously written for a reason but the Python script still works.

4) The only reason that I see for using the Python version is that it is easier to modify to suit for some special purpose because it is Python and not C++.